# Session object is lost in .net web forms app after short period of time

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, webforms, iis-7

I have .net app which is using session object in few places. 
They work just fine locally but when I'm deploying the app to the server the session object works relatively briefly, 1-2 minutes and after that it doesn't work until the next time I'll update the dll file of the app and reload the app.

Any idea what is wrong in the server configuration for this to be happening?

Comment: Why do you think its a "server configuration" vs, say, something in your app? What is your session store? Web farm?Load balancing/affinity? Not much to go on other than guessing....

Comment: @EdSF I'm checking if the session object is null in the code and if it is then redirect to specific page and thats the behavior I'm getting on the server, compared to the local environment where its working just fine. Session is stored InProc.